# How to add an `iframe` as a background in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

How to add an `iframe` as a background in HTML5...
I've an animation and its on a HTML5 page. And I want to put this html page as a background in another HTML5 page... what should I do ?
My code is this one:

```
<iframe src="js/particles/background/index.html" seamless width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
                    <li style="transform: scaleX(-1);opacity: 0.9; background-image: url(https://sites.google.com/site/tutorialebackground/_/rsrc/1367281771560/home/fundo-transparente-de-png/Sem%20t%C3%ADtulo.png);"><!--image background-->
                       <iframe src="js/particles/background/index.html" seamless width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
                        <div class="overlay"></div>
                        <div class="container-fluid">
```

I even tried to put a transparent background...

Someone can help?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you tried absolute positioning the `iframe` and setting it's `z-index` to something like `-999`?

Comment: Yes, I did but didnt work either !